# Поиск по командам Linux

Tags: linux

Такое задание: 
 Некоторая директория содержит каталоги вида «20180201». Выведите список всех файлов с расширением «log» и их размеры из каталогов, созданных в 2018 году.

Вроде команды для поиска ввожу, а как всё скомпоновать - не знаю.

Comment: и что вы сделали для выполнения **вашего** задания? изложите это прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]